# Call server function using ajax with jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to use in my application ajax and jquery together.
How can I call server function using ajax with jquery ?

Thanks,
kukuwka

Answer (score 1):

The best source for this kind information is the jQuery manual. It comes with plenty of examples. Have a look at http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Comment: Thanks.It is good tutorial.But I didn't find example how I can create function on server side for using ajax

Comment: You usually do that by returning JSON from the server, but the details depend on the server-side environment you are working on. For example for ASP.NET MVC you would probably want to return a JSONResult. It's impossible to tell you more than this just by looking at your opening post though.